# How do I create a website subdirectory and link a button to it

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, socket.io, subdirectory

Me and the boys made a IRL version of among us that could be even better with the help of a website. I asked a few questions searched around and have learned a lot about how to write html, CSS, java script code, and what are and how to use websockets. However I only have the front page with 2 buttons(Host and Join).

My question is how to click the "Host" or "Join" button and it brings me to a URL like "localhost:4000 **/create** " where I can start work on the create room system. (I think the title might be asking a different question but I have no idea what to ask so that's the closest I can put it into words ,correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something similar to this:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='localhost:4000';">
  Host
</button>
```